# Alternative way of connecting to PIL library?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-imaging-library

Usually the library PIL is connected as follows:

```
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
```

I would like to connect it this way:

```
import PIL
```

but my version does not work. Here's the code:

```
import os, sys
import tkinter
import PIL

main = tkinter.Tk()

catalogImg1 = 'imgs'
nameImg1 = 'n.jpg'
pathImg1 = os.path.join(catalogImg1, nameImg1)

openImg = PIL.Image.open(pathImg1)

renderImg = PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage(openImg)
tkinter.Label(main, image=renderImg).pack()

main.mainloop()
```

The error message is:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Python33\projects\PIL_IMAGETK\ImageTK_photoimage - копия.py", line
>   11, in 
>       openImg = PIL.Image.open(pathImg1) AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Image'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Importing a package (`PIL`) does not automatically import subpackages, submodules (`PIL.Image`, `PIL.ImageTk`). (Unless the package itself do it).

Explicitly import the submodules.

Replace following line:

```
import PIL
```

with:

```
import PIL.Image
import PIL.ImageTk
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because, `Image` is a submodule within the PIL package i.e. It is not a function or class. Importing a package does not automatically import its submodules.

If you want to use the `PIL` namespace, you can import the module as follows:

```
import PIL.Image
openImg = PIL.Image.open(pathImg1)
```

If you want to import all the submodules of `PIL`, you can do the following

```
from PIL import *
openImg = Image.open(pathImg1)
```